# Invoking the emplace() method for std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, emplace

What is the correct way to invoke the `emplace()` method for `std::vector`, given the following template declarations? The requirement is to emplace an element inside the vector `impl_tree` at a given position, after the construction of the `tree` class template object.

(Note only relevant source code has been reproduced)

```
template<typename T1>
class node {
public:
    node(T1&);
private:
    T1 data;
};

template typename<T1, T2>
class tree {
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node<T1>>> impl_tree;
};
```

Comment: `T1 data; impl_tree.emplace(pos, std::make_shared<node<T1>>(data);`

Comment: @Quentin I meant `pos` to be an iterator. I guess I should have spelled it out.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik nevermind, I mixed up `emplace` and `emplace_back`. My bad.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Please do not use the comments section for answering questions. Use the answer section for that. Hence the name.